# Cannot copy a file using "File.copy" method in java

Tags: java, file, file-io, io, ioerror

I am new to Java.

While I am trying to copy a file using "File.copy" method in java.
The process end without errors.

But the file I need to copy is created with only one weired character (I think it is an file end character). and it has no content other than it.

Here is my source code,

```
var sourceFile = new File("mySourceFile.txt")
var destinyFile = new File("myDestinyFile.txt");
Files.copy(sourceFile.toPath(), destinyFile.toPath());
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Did you close any open OutputStreams that write to the source file before attempting to copy it?

Comment: @VGR  Nope I didnt

Comment: You should close all OutputStreams, so the file’s contents are fully written.  You might also want to print out the size of the file before you copy it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

The problem is that there are outputstreams already open for the same destiny file I have to.

So it File.copy() method cannot write on the file.

Answer (score 0):

it doesnt matter if the file you will copy has one or hundred character. You say the process ends without errors. Does it mean it works fine or it does someting wrong but you get no error. If this is the case you can try to take the full path like this:

```
    var sourceFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Kevin\\test1.txt").toPath();
    var destinyFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Kevin\\test2.txt").toPath();
    
    Files.copy(sourceFile, destinyFile);
```

Comment: Sorry this is similar to the original code I used.

Comment: You need to give us more information about your problem